# Bluetooth Connectivity of Android Device with Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am working Android base Attendance door lock application. Currently the application works when card is tap, Attendance is marked. Now i have join it with arduino based door lock. Arduino is connected through Bluetooth with Android Application. when android device goes to sleep mode connection of Bluetooth is disconnected. Is there any way that when device goes to sleep mode connection will not be disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it programmatically like bottom.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
```

Or you can set it from `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

More info: [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock)